# LaravelでSQLiteを使いたい

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

ご閲覧ありがとうございます.

LaravelでSQLiteを使用したいのですが、
サーバーを起動してデータベースを使用するページに移動すると

> Database (database.sqlite) does not exist.(データベース（database.sqlite）は存在しません。)
>   と`InvalidArgumentException`が発生してしまいます.

.envの環境変数等のパスを色々と調べて試したのですが上手く動かず...
どうかご教授の方よろしくお願いいたします.

### database.sqlite階層

`PROJECT\database\database.sqlite`

### .env

```
<<略>>

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

<<略>>
```

### database.php

```
<<略>>

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

<<略>>
```

### HelloController.php

```
<<略>>

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class HelloController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $items = DB::select('select * from people');
        return view('hello.index', ['items' => $items]);
    }
}
```

【keyword】
- Windows10(64bit)
- PHP 5.6.32 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2017 16:00:49)
- Laravel Framework version 4.2.22
- sqlite3 -version 3.21.0 2017-10-24 18:55:49 1a584e499906b5c87ec7d43d4abce641fdf017c42125b083109bc77c4de48827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました.

SQLiteはサーバー不要のファイルベースで動作するデータベースであり、
`.env`から必要の無い`DB_HOST`, `DB_PORT`, `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME`, `DB_PASSWORD`をコメントアウトすることで動作しました.

すると続いて

> [PDOException]
>   could not find driver

が発生しましたが、こちらは`php.ini`の`extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`のコメントアウトを外すことで解決しました.